# Defining functions to determine HashTable stats

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

Ok so I have a class that reads a dictionary file into hash table to that compares words inputted by the user and returns suggested words. My program implements a HashTable that uses linked lists to create buckets for the values. I have finished the program and I am having trouble developing a method to print the maximum chain length, % of buckets used within my table, and average chain length.

```
public class DictionaryTable {

    public String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");//stores uses working director
    public String DICT_FILENAME = "\\src\\dictionary.txt";
    public String D_PATH = workingDir + DICT_FILENAME;

    private int DICT_SIZE; //determines size of dictionary
    final private Bucket[] array;
```

The method above is included to give an idea of the private variables used in my class and the hash function. And I also provided my hash just in case its needed.

```
private int hash(String key) {
        return (key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % DICT_SIZE;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `HashMap`? What is the reason for implementing this yourself?

Comment: Oh, sorry its part of an assignment so I implemented my own table

Comment: This kind of stuff is hard. You could look at the source code for HashMap for inspiration.

Comment: I dont need the hashmap source code the program is finished and working im just have trouble adding methods in my Dictionary class to return the methods I listed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble developing a method to determine the load factor,

The load factor is how much keys you will allow to be inserted in the hashtable *before* you double the table. E.g. if the size of your table is 32 and your load factor is 50% then you will double your table when you have 16 elements.
The load factor can be a parameter passed by the client of your hashtable i.e. configuration and can also have a default value which in real implementation is a value that depends on the hashtable variant (a usual value is ~75%)

> maximum chain length,

You should not take into account the chain length but the load factor (read previous paragraph). Deciding on the chain length is not a good idea because you would end up doubling your table just because 1 bucket has been "saturated" and the rest of your table could be fine.

> % of buckets used within my table

You can not determine that. Your hash function and how good it is determines the distribution. Unless you have a really really good hash function you won't be able to utilize the majority of your buckets in your hash table (clustering effect)

> average chain length.

This again will depend on your hash function and collisions. You do **not** determine this.

Comment: Ok I would only like to be able to print these stats.